# Nuxt ignoring babel on build process

Tags: vue.js, webpack, babeljs, nuxt.js

https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build#babel

I originally left the presets as default.

I then followed the suggestions on
https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/1776

However this dealt more with pipelines

I am just trying to get it to convert the es6 to es5 (import chief among the reasons)

I get the same result or a complete failure no matter if i add the .babelrc, adjust package.json, adjust nuxt.config.js or a combination of them.

currently i have adjusted my nuxt.config.js to:

```
/*
 ** Build configuration
 */
build: {
    babel: {
        presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
        configFile: false,
        babelrc: false,
        plugins: ['@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import']
    }
}
```

When i upload the entire .nuxt folder to my server (running plesk using phusion passenger)

I get the following error

```
/var/www/vhosts/website.com/app/client/server.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { stringify } from 'querystring'
```

My site root is

```
/var/www/vhosts/website.com/app/client/
```

The first line of server.js

```
import { stringify } from 'querystring
```

Changing this to

```
var stringify = require("querystring").stringify
```

Eliminates the error however i would need to go through page after page to remove this. My understanding is i can progamically adjust this using babel. But no matter what ive tried the file stays the same.

I did use the Nuxt CLI to automatically set up babel and webpack but using the above build config is not the default. I have attempted to play with it but i get the same result

I added babel/polyfill to try and get around the import issues without any success

Comment: Because nuxt compile it's own sources, not external.kqunch script that he have no control of

Comment: Im definately starting to see that nuxtjs has a lot of control